# How to create tag in Select2 despite finding the term in the current option list

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, tagging

In Select2, the function `createTag()` is not run when the text entered by the user fully matches one of the options.

So, if I have the following grouped list in my `<select>` (notice that Panama appears twice):

```
- OptionGroup: City
  - Option: Kampala
  - Option: Panama
  - Option: Vienna
- OptionGroup: Country
  - Option: Austria
  - Option: Panama
  - Option: Uganda
```

I want to be able to add a tag with `Panama`, so that I can later search in both country and city. But the function `createTag()` is not even called by Select2.

This is my call to Select2:

```
$(selector).select2({
    placeholder: "Start typing to filter...",
    allowClear: true,
    tags: true,
    createTag: function (params) {
        var term = $.trim(params.term);

        if (term === '') {
            return null;
        }

        return {
            id: 'text=' + term,
            text: 'Text: "' + term + '"',
            newTag: true // add additional parameters
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it, modifying the source code of Select2, file `data/tags.js`:

1. I added a boolean option named `createTagOnMatch` with default value `false`.
2. I checked that this option is not *trueish* before returning when a matching item is found.

You can find the modified version here:

https://github.com/jotaelesalinas/select2/tree/develop

and with the changes in the commit here:

https://github.com/jotaelesalinas/select2/commit/7bb6b92f6eaba9e4c8ae66c954ab9732447c464c

I created a pull request in the original Select2, which is pending:

https://github.com/select2/select2/pull/5534